# How To Turn A Jtextarea Comparable With String

Tags: java, jtextarea

I'm Trying To Make A Chat Bot But It Always Comes Up With A Error When I Type:

```
if(Write == "hi"){
    Reply.setText("HI!");
}
```

It Will Come  With The Error: `jtextarea incomparable with String`

What Shall I Do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much context in the question to work with, but I suppose you are looking for

```
if ("hi".equals(Write.getText()))
```

By the way, *never* compare strings with `==` unless you really want them to be exactly the same instance of the String class.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

You can not compare completely different objects with each other by using `==`. `Write` is of type `JTextArea` and `"hi"` is of type `String`. Those objects have nothing in common thus the compiler complaints.

---

### Solution

You probably wanted to compare the **text stored inside** `JTextArea` with the text `"hi"`. You access this text by using the `JTextArea#getText` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--)).

Now note that you never (except you know what you do) should compare `String`s by using `==`. The result will not be what you expected. Use `String#equals` instead. Here's more on this topic: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

So your code should probably look like:

```
if ("hi".equals(Write.getText())) {
    Reply.setText("HI!");
}
```

---

### Naming conventions

Last note that you should stick to **naming conventions**. Variable names, also method names, should always begin with a **lowercase character**. Uppercase is only used for class names (and constants). So you should rather write `write` and `reply`:

```
if ("hi".equals(write.getText())) {
    reply.setText("HI!");
}
```

Comment: sorry, but coz im a nooby i probally wont understand all of this

Comment: @OtsWng That is no problem, just tell me what exactly confuses you and I will explain it in more detail.

Comment: th.e guy at the top already explained it to me but he didn't explain what i really needed, because i needed something more easier for me to type it. like for example if i typed hi, it would randomize all the reply statements but i didn't know how to store all of it in one variable, and print it out. for example if i said hi, it would either say:hi,how r u, and so on.

Comment: @OtsWng Mhh, your that does not seem to be related to your question. Please create a new question with all information necessary. You may then link the follow-up question here.

Comment: i didn't now how to randomize them and i didn't know how to use:`Math.random` so i just scraped the whole chatbot idea because i didn't know much code that time. also i found out that i shouldn't use:`if ("hi".equals(write.getText())) {` because what if i said: hi :-] it wouldn't say hi so i should use: `if ("hi".contains(write.getText())) {` so when it contains it it would randomize then print. can u help me

Comment: i'l, try but i ran out of questions untill tomorrow. i'll try!